# Get last date from a column on a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for help on the following:

How do I get the last date from a column in sheet1 returned in a cell of sheet2

I tried it with:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A ; ROW(A:A) =MAX( FILTER(ROW(A:A) ; NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))))
```

but this results in an error

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of error? Could you share the spreadsheet with us?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following formula will find the maximum date in column A:

`=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A))`

See example file I've prepared: [find maximum date](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdC1VeG9aMTVFNXFHMF81SGk5ZkRUS2c&usp=sharing)

Comment: It works like a charm.

Do you have an idea what I can do if the collumn doesn´t contain dates, but text ?

Comment: That indeed is another question. Please read this section of the [faq#howtoask] how to deal with answered questions.

Comment: You´re right. I have posted a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, you might want to change the "share" permissions on the example you've prepared.

Comment: @XavierCasto Done, thanks for that !!

Comment: A [user](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/92116/hema) tried to comment: "=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A)) is not working for the input 15/1/2015 15/1/2015 21/1/2015 "

Answer (score 0):

To find the last value entered in col A (of sheet1), also try

```
=+sort(Sheet1!A:A,row(Sheet1!A:A)*(Sheet1!A:A<>""),)
```

and see if that works ?